# My Search isnt working, doesnt go to /products/

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

If I go to /products/ and add in the end anything, It will Search from all the products, but when I try to press the search button, it doesnt do anything, not even go to /products/.

I dont know if I should use Button instead of input, I'm following a tutorial and it works there

```
const Search = ({ history }) => {

const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

const searchSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (keyword.trim()) {
        history.push(`/products/${keyword}`);
    } else{
        history.push("/products");
    }
};

return (
<Fragment>
<form className="searchBox" onSubmit={searchSubmitHandler}>
 <input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Search a Product ..."
    onChange={(e) => setKeyword(e.target.value)}
 />
 <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</Fragment>
);   
};
export default Search here
```

Comment: I think the reason is due to ```history```, because I tried your code without that like ```console.log(`/products/${keyword}`)```, it worked

Comment: How should the code be? 
`
if (keyword.trim()){
push(`/products${keyboard}`) `

it says push is not defined

Comment: which ```react router dom``` version do you use?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",

Comment: react-router-dom v6 does not support ```useHistory (history)```. Use ```useNavigate (navigate)``` in here.

Answer (score 0):

Try canceling
e.preventDefault ();

Comment: it does search but instead going to /products/$keyword it goes to /Search?